# Is there any way to change background of buttons on user click in angular?

Tags: angular, button

I want to change the background of button on user click but the other buttons to go back to original state. how shall i do this using ngClass in angular 10.
(note: i dont want to do this using css only)

Comment: what have u tried so far? please attach your attempt

Comment: If you want to control multiple buttons at once, I would suggest you to create a service in which you will have a list like object in which you add all the buttons you want to control. Then have several methods to help you achive what you need. Something like.  setButtonActive(button: ElementRef): void. and set its background-color for the desired color and set all other to the defualt. Please be aware if you change CSS from type script use Renderer2 class. Another ideia would be using a BehaviorSubject in the service and notify all the observers about the current button clicked